# picking PDF files using Intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Hey I am new in android I have a requirement to choose `pdf` files using     `Intent`. I am using this code to set type of MIME.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("pdf/*")
```

But it's not working the way I want, please provide me any suggestions or can I make some changes to the existing code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this `intent.setType("application/pdf");`

Comment: how to open only word file via intent??

Comment: just set the mime type for the word file for example  for .docx file mime type will be : application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document so intent.setType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");

Comment: Microsoft Office MIME types are given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc

Comment: My system's file picker shows Google Drive as a provider. If I click Drive, I can select a non-PDF file. How to get around this besides eliminating Drive entirely by using EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY?

Answer (score 4):

Try Below Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```