# How to get only .PDF file through Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT into google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I have tried to use the following code to get pdf file from intent but it's showing me all kind of files.I want file chooser menu to show only .pdf files.

```
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code based from this post: [picking PDF files using Intent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265469/picking-pdf-files-using-intent-in-android).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps!